# NSNumberFormatter encoding

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I'm using NSNumberFormatter to convert number into RUB currency representation.
This is my code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setCurrencyCode:@"RUB"];

NSLog(@"String With Number:%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:sum]);
```

Everything works fine while I use simulator but at real device I keep getting string with broken encoding.

Example:

What I should get:

RUB99.00

What I really get:

99,00¬†—А—Г–±

How could I fix it? And why it happens?

Comment: You can try setting the locale to number formatter.

Comment: This was probably an attempt to produce a string `99.00 рублей`, which got misprinted (currency is placed after the amount in Russian locale).

Comment: You should be able to make simulator produce the result expected in the locale of your choice by switching the locale of the simulator to the locale of your device. Press the "home" button, flip to the page with settings, choose general/international/region format, and pick the target region. When I did this in the simulator, I got `99,00 руб` output as expected.